# Rails LEFT JOIN searching and json

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_records
  attr_accessor :service_record
end

class ServiceRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :plant
end

class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :service_record
end
```

I am wanting to perform a query that left joins each service record on an address and each plant on a service record. So, for example, if I have a single address that has 3 service records, I want to get 3 results that repeat the address fields for each service record while also containing the plant information for each service record.

So far I have my query looking like so (using Rails 5):

```
Address.left_joins(service_records: :plant)
```

That returns me the correct number of repeating address results (i.e. 3 from my above example).

The next step I am struggling to figure out is to then return that resulting query as a JSON structure that contains each address and each unique service record. So something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 1
      plant: {
        id: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 2
      plant: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 3
      plant: {
        id: 3
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If you notice, I do have an `attr_accessor :service_record` on my Address model, however I am not sure that is the correct approach to get what I need. Any help or alternate approach to get what I am looking for would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From your query, you can use Rails as_json with options to achieve what you want. You could do something like this:

```
addresses = Address.left_joins(service_records: :plant)
addresses.as_json
# => [
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd"
  }
]
```

Next step is to include associations

```
addresses.as_json(include: :service_record)
[
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 2
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 3
    }
  }
]
```

And finally :

```
addresses.as_json(include: { service_record: { include: :plant } })
# => [
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 1
      plant: {
        id: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 2
      plant: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 3
      plant: {
        id: 3
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can then fine tune the result. More on this on the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).

**UPDATE**

If you are sure that you will have only one record in the service_records array, you could do :

```
def service_record
  service_records.first
end
```

then do this

```
addresses.as_json(methods: :service_record)
[
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 2
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    address: "1234 Street Rd",
    service_record: {
      id: 3
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: `service_record` isn't an "official" attribute on the address model. I am only able to access `service_records` since that is the association between the models.

Comment: Why did you set the service_record attr_accessor?

Comment: I added that there as a possible idea. I am currently not setting it anywhere. I was hoping there is a way to set that equal to the `service_record` that gets joined onto the address during the query, but it's looking like that is not possible.

Comment: If you are sure that you will have only one service_record, you could have a method. I will update my answer to show you how.

Comment: That is the problem, I am not sure there will only be one. There can be zero, one, or many service records per address and I need a json entry for each one with its corresponding address.